# Extract specific columns into multiple .CSVs, error in code

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have an excel file where each column has varying products codes, descriptions, unit of measure, and 5 different prices (one for each distributor) in this order.

Workbook as it is:
[image: Workbook as it is]

I need to make 5 distinct .csv files, named after each distributor, each with code, discount (normally 0), one of the prices, MU and description, in this order.

What one of the CSVs should look like:
[image: What one of the CSVs should look like]

I can move columns around alright, the issues is that I can't seem to find a way to save the CSVs.
The code that I have (not mine) stops as it seems to be "unable to access the .csv" as it tries to save it.

```
Sub FornitoriToCSV()

    Const FLDR = "C:\Users\HER-XV\Desktop" 'where to save files
    Dim rng As Range, wb As Workbook, i As Long, rws As Long
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'data table
    rws = rng.Rows.Count 'how many rows of data?

    For i = 4 To rng.Columns.Count 'loop for each client column (starting at col4)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'add workbook
        'copy data to workbook
        With wb.Sheets(1)
            .Range("A1").Resize(rws).Value = rng.Columns(1).Value
            .Range("B1").Value = "Discount"
            .Range("B2").Resize(rws - 1).Value = 0
            .Range("C1").Resize(rws).Value = rng.Columns(i).Value 'client data
            .Range("D1").Resize(rws).Value = rng.Columns(3).Value
            .Range("E1").Resize(rws).Value = rng.Columns(2).Value
        End With
        'save the file using the client name
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=FLDR & rng.Cells(1, i).Value & ".csv", _
                  FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
        wb.Close False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you manually save to that folder?

Comment: What is the exact value of `rng.Cells(1, i).Value` in the case of error? And what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: As noted in your previous post, you will need to adjust the location of `FLDR` to some place you have access to.  Also make sure your client names don't contain any characters not allowed in a file name.

Comment: I already changed location, didn't help.
The characters are just letters, no special chars.

Comment: I modifed the path to desktop so i'm sure i can save there.

Comment: the value of rng.Cells(1, i).Value is the first code of the excel with no issue, i get the issue in another language so it's close to "Impossible to access Client A.csv" with options to retry or cancel, retry doesn't help.

Comment: Changed path in code as to reflect last attempts, tried also to point to "C:" and "C:\Users\HER-XV"

Comment: Your `FLDR` need to end with a backslash otherwise you try to save to `C:\Users\HER-XV\DesktopFILENAME.csv` instead of `C:\Users\HER-XV\Desktop\FILENAME.csv`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That solved it!
Nevermind! adding a backlash worked!
How can I flag your comment as answer?

Comment: @Ead Comments cannot be marked as answer. Instead I voted to close the question because it was only a typo (which is likely not helpful for future readers).